# Skip the joins based on the condition without dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am having a scenerio like i am having two table with the name `tbl1` and `tb2`

```
Select * from tbl1 t1 inner join tb2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.id
```

The above sample query here i need to achive is that i need to perform this inner join based on the condition. (i.e) I will pass input parameter `IsJoin` as true means, i can perform inner join else not. I am not preferring dynamic query. Kindly let me know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you go by the `Logical Query processing phases` when a query executes then you'll see that `From clause and joins` executes as the first thing in the query then follows the `where` clause and the rest. So i believe there is no other way to not to compute an `inner join` except to write a dynamic query.. i hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

There's just one way to do that then - using `IF` and `ELSE` statements

```
IF <YOUR CONDITION>
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl1 t1
    INNER JOIN tb2 t2
        ON t1.Id = t2.id;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl1 t1;
END
```

If it's just few conditions, then it's fine to do this using multiple statements, however if it's tons of joins based on conditions - it's easier to maintain Dynamic SQL. And it becomes much more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i cant prefer this because i am having more table to joins based on different condition. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: You could try to do what @Parado suggested - but performance might be not that great. I'd personally go for Dynamic SQL here as there's no other real option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
declare @IsJoin numeric(1,0)
select @IsJoin = 1

Select * from tbl1 t1 
left join tb2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.id
                 and @IsJoin = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But Select * from tbl1 t1 
left join tb2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.id
               where @IsJoin  = 1 will also work but my doubt is whether left join will run in back end???. But i need an result as i should skip that left join

Comment: @user2003780 Do you want to return data from `tb2`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve all columns of t1 and t2 whether join or not

```
DECLARE @IsJoin bit = 1 -- 1 for true; 0 for false

SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    tbl1 t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.id and @IsJoin = 1
WHERE 
    (@IsJoin = 0 OR t2.id is not null) -- Keep the inner join behavior
```